# employee binomial distribution

Tags: binomial-distribution

Can anyone let me know if I am following the correct format/procedures in solving this problem and have came up with the correct answer?

If I have 80% of the employees that have their biweekly Wages deposit directly to their bank.  If I select a random samples of  8 employees. What is the probability that 3 of the 8 sampled employees use direct deposit?

$$P(x=3)=\binom83 \times (0.80)^3 \times (1-0.80)^{8-3} = 0.0092$$